# Finding correct cmake configuration for yaml-cpp library

Tags: c++, cmake, yaml-cpp

I was trying to use [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) in my project. It took me half an hour to correctly link the library by experimenting with the following names. After I finally stumbled across them in [this file](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/master/yaml-cpp-config.cmake.in), I settled for this:

```
find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED)
include_directories(${YAML_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES})
```

It works, but the way I was searching for those seems brainless.

How is it remotely possible to figure out the correct name of the include variables? It could be `YAML_LIBS`, `YAML_LIBRARY`, `YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES`, there is no standard, right? What is the appropriate way to determine the correct cmake config for most c++ libraries?

Thank you.

Comment: RTFM ;-): By reading the documentation of Findyaml-cpp and if that is not enough by inspecting the source of Findyaml-cpp in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH

Comment: Or by looking at the `cmake.in` file: https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/master/yaml-cpp-config.cmake.in

Comment: So is this a recipe? When installing a new library look for the `.cmake.in` file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most of `FindXXX.cmake` scripts have *usage description* at the top of them (as CMake comments started `#`). The same is true about `XXXConfig.cmake` (or `xxx-config.cmake`) scripts.

Command `find_package(XXX)` uses one of such scripts (the one which actually exists). So, before using this approach for discover the package, make sure that you have read the description "embedded" into such script.

In your case, `yaml-cpp-config.cmake` file (created in the build or in the install directory) contains following description:

```
# - Config file for the yaml-cpp package
# It defines the following variables
#  YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR - include directory
#  YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES    - libraries to link against
```

so proper usage of results of `find_package(yaml-cpp)` is

```
include_directories(${YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(<your-target> ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: All I need. Thank you.