# How to use a c++ library written in a cmake project into another cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake, yaml-cpp

I am newbie to cmake and I am pretty sure this is the problem I am facing here.

I am trying to use the [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) library which is written in cmake project into my own cmake project. I run the following commands to build and install the yaml-cpp in it's own directory. `mkdir build`, `cd build`, `cmake ..`, `make`, and then `sudo make install` and no errors occured after running those commands.

now in my own project I am having a c++ code file in a proper cmake project. To use the yaml-cpp library I am including it with the `#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"`, and in the *CmakeLists.txt* file in that subdirectory I am adding the following two:

```
find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(yaml-cpp)
```

however when I try to compile the project it gives me the following output:

```
handstandForm.cpp:(.text+0x4820): undefined reference to `YAML::LoadFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
```

I want to point out that the project compiles perfectly and run without any errors when deleting any lines of codes using the yaml-cpp library. what could be the problem? Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding correct cmake configuration for c++ library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036144/finding-correct-cmake-configuration-for-c-library) The `target_link_libraries()` command requires *at least* two arguments. The first argument must be an existing CMake target, which would be *your* library/executable that 
 you want to link the library to.

Comment: no it does not.